# How to know which members have embedded SQL

Tags: ibm-midrange

I have a library on IBM i which has many source files and members. I have to perform some operation on members which have embedded SQL in it. Is there an easy way by which I can identify only those members which have embedded SQL whether member is compiled or not.

Answer (score 4):

Since you commented they all contain 'EXEC SQL' blocks, you should be able to issue a FNDSTRPDM command similar to this to print a list of the matching source members.

```
FNDSTRPDM STRING('EXEC SQL') FILE(LIBNAME/QRPGLESRC) MBR(*ALL) OPTION(*NONE) PRTMBRLIST(*YES)
```

Comment: This way we will be getting those member also which have 'EXEC SQL' inside string. Suppose some member have comment which contains EXEC SQL. This also requires running command for each source file (which  may be time taking).

Comment: FNDSTRPDM searches *ALL members for any occurrence of the string.  If you have 'EXEC SQL'' in comments of a source that doesn't execute Sql that's a problem, but it doesn't take long to run (and can be submitted if that's a concern)

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about HLL source with SQL functions (i.e., RPG SQL)?

If so, you can probably look at the source member type.

If you're taking about untyped source members with just SQL instructions, then you'll have to read the source member and determine if it has the SQL instructions you are interested in.

Comment: I am talking about RPG and COBOL members with member type SQLRPGLE, SQLRPG, SQLCBL etc. These have normal EXEC SQL blocks with SQL statements.

Comment: Then I would suggest using the member type... this is what PDM & RDi use to determine which compiler to invoke.

Comment: I have seen EXEC SQLs in RPGLE member types also. If we are filtering on the basis of member types then we can miss some members.

Comment: EXEC SQL is valid in RPGLE.  If you don't use member type, you'll have to read the source member and look for an uncommented EXEC SQL function in order to determine if it contains embedded SQL.  FWIW: Member type is the best data element to use ... as I mentioned, PDM & RDi use this to determine which compiler to invoke. If the member type is wrong, the source probably won't compile.

Comment: However, I had used SYSPROGRAMSTAT system view to identify the objects in which there is SQL statement. I am looking in ORIGINAL_SOURCE_FILE column of it to get member details. But this requires member to be compiled and when objects restored by save file, then ORIGINAL_SOURCE_FILE column has library referring to that from where save file is created.

Comment: Have you considered changing the member type of RPGLE members that contain EXEC SQL to SQLRPGLE?  What kind of operations do you want to perform on the members?